# C# multiple threads calling single method at specific interval

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, stock

I will try to make the question as simple so that it is easy to get an idea of the scenario. I am trying to build a stock related application for school project, which is fetching data from the web for a particular stock. So the user inputs stock name in a text box and after clicking the button, the name of the stock is passed to the method downloading data for that particular stock. Now i want that method to be called on every second for the same stock so that user can get the latest updates. Till now no problem. But when the user wants to monitor more than one stocks, i need to dive into threading. As for each stock there will be a thread will be calling the update stock method every second. So for example there are 5 stocks so there should be 5 threads that are working simultaneously calling the method every second to update the results. I hope i have made the problem clear to understand.

To accomplish this i am using the System.Threading.Timer in the button click event and it is calling the method for stock update. But the problem is that when i enter the first stock the method is called only 2 times, for the second stock it is being called for 6 times and for 3rd stock more than 12 times. What is the reason behind such weird behavior.

Any idea if there is any other way around to achieve what i am trying to do.
Following is the code i am working on.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("","","","","","test", "test");
    int i= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    string stock = textBox1.Text + ":"+i;

    System.Threading.Timer tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick,stock,1000,2000);
}

public void Tick(object stock)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        string maindata = stock.ToString();
        string[] testing = maindata.Split(':');
        byte[] data = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("some url where i am getting data from");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.DownloadDataCompleted += delegate(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            data = e.Result;
        };
        wc.DownloadDataAsync(uri);
        while (wc.IsBusy)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        string[] s = strData.Split('{');
        string data1 = s[4];
        string[] data2 = data1.Split('}');
        string final = "[{" + data2[0] + "}]";

        Form1 obj = new Form1();
        List<Form1> jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Form1>>(final);

        dataGridView1.Rows[System.Convert.ToInt32(testing[1]) - 1].Cells[0].Value = jarray[0].Symbol;
        dataGridView1.Rows[System.Convert.ToInt32(testing[1]) - 1].Cells[1].Value = jarray[0].Ask;
        dataGridView1.Rows[System.Convert.ToInt32(testing[1]) - 1].Cells[2].Value = jarray[0].Volume;
        dataGridView1.Rows[System.Convert.ToInt32(testing[1]) - 1].Cells[3].Value = jarray[0].Bid;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since with every click you are creating a new `Timer`. This will mean with every subsequent click, more timers will respond so you start getting the events twice, 4 times, ....

Move this line out of click and put it in the initialization of the form:

```
System.Threading.Timer tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick,stock,1000,2000);
```

This does not mean I fully approve your approach since that has nothing to do with the question you are asking.

Comment: he wants a separate timer for *each* stock, so this is intentional

Comment: Actually i need this timer to be created every time a new stock is added so i have kept this line System.Threading.Timer tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick,stock,1000,2000);
in the button click event

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [Asynchronous Programming Using Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx).  On every tick (using just 1 timer) you should launch a delegate asynchronously to get your values for each stock the user requests.

Answer (score 0):

@Prashant - Obviously your approach is not correct.  What you actually want to happen is to have multiple threads which will tick at different intervals.  As Aliostad hinted at your approach isn't correct.

> System.Threading.Timer is a simple,
>   lightweight timer that uses callback
>   methods and is served by thread pool
>   threads. It is not recommended for use
>   with Windows Forms, because its
>   callbacks do not occur on the user
>   interface thread.
>   System.Windows.Forms.Timer is a better
>   choice for use with Windows Forms. For
>   server-based timer functionality, you
>   might consider using
>   System.Timers.Timer, which raises
>   events and has additional features.

What I would do is use a mutex approach to determine if a new thread is required.  I would pass the name of the stock and within the thread itself start the timer.  If you wanted to a feature to "pause" or "stop" a stock from being watched would be easy enough.

The current class your using is threaded your approach itself is flawed.

```
As for each stock there will be a thread will be calling the update stock method every second. So for example there are 5 stocks so there should be 5 threads that are working simultaneously calling the method every second to update the results. I hope i have made the problem clear to understand.
```

- Except this isn't what you are doing.  What you are actualy doing is starting a new timer thread for each time the button is pressed( for every stock ) which of course is NOT what you actually want to do ( based on your own statements ).

Comment: The OP does not have a single timer - as you stated yourself he's creating *a new timer* on each button click. So that means there are separate timers for each stock and your subsequent explanation doesn't make sense (regardless of whether the approach is right or not)

Comment: @Broken - Honestly I wasn't entirely sure if that explaination actually did make sense or not ( one of those makes sense in my head ) statements.

Comment: I thought of the same approach that you have suggested by creating a thread and starting off the timer from the thread itself. But the problem that i was facing was when i create next thread with other stock name and trigger a new timer from the thread itself it keeps on waiting there to access the method for an infinite time. Subsequent threads were not able to get access to the method as the method was thread safe and was locked. So the first thread use to keep on accessing the method. I even tried to abort the current thread after it finished executing the method.

Answer (score 0):

"But when the user wants to monitor more than one stocks, i need to dive into threading". Not true. Now I don't want to spoil a perfectly good opportunity to dive headfirst into threading, but you don't need to here. Why not refresh all stocks at the same time?

So each time the timer ticks, you download the prices for all the stocks in one go. If you have control of the serverside interface (where you get the data from), make a method that accepts a collection of stocktickers and returns a collection of stockprices. If the server only returns one at a time, you get them on by one in a loop.

Also when you really want to have something that responds quickly, don't poll for new prices every second but have the server notify you when something has changed by subscribing to an event for instance. Some stocks will not move for minutes, while other move very quickly. For most trading purposes, a full second is a lifetime. If you're on WPF, look into DataBinding and INotifyPropertyChanged. That fits extremely well for this type of problem.

GJ

Comment: I do accept that what you suggested will work for me but the case is that there are many exchanges and each exchange has lots of stock listed, so fetching data for each stock from all the exchange on every tick would eat up the resources and time because i am able to get only single stock data from the URL. In that case i thought the user enters the stock name that can be passed to the url and the price information can be updated on every second. In fact i am trying to emulate a real time stock prices application. For this i thought threading would be the option for me to try.